# Disqus anchor at end of semantic URL

Tags: url, anchor, semantics, disqus

I'm developing a WP based site that has semantic URLs such as this:

```
http://mysite.com/category/article/#disqus_thread
```

Referring to the article's Disqus section at the bottom of that page doesn't work using the above method. I'm not entirely sure how anchors work when not using direct file URLs. How would you approach this? I'm using the Disqus 2012 script.

Answer (score 0):

It should work just fine without the final slash before the hash, like this:

http://mysite.com/category/article#disqus_thread